# Redmine Not working from other computer

Tags: redmine

I have installed redmine 3.2 version in centos 7 and it's working in localhost:3000 in the same machine. but it's not working form other pc in the same network.
I have allow the 3000 port and tried to stop firewalld also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue with redmine startup cmd before i used " ruby bin/rails server webrick -e production -p 3000 " it will work only in localhost. Now used this command " ruby bin/rails server webrick -e production -b 192.168.XX.XX -p 3000 " with ipaddress it work fine.